# cfdisk filesystem type for storing videos on a harddrive

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I have a spare harddrive that I want to store my videos on. They are in mp4 format. I'm using cfdisk to create a new clean partition on the drive. What filesystem type should i make it (linux,HPFS/NTFS,FAT16...)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning which distribution you're using and if you're planning to access the data from any other operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends on what OS you'll be accessing from...ext4 or ntfs depending

Answer (score 0):

If you want the filesystem to be readable from multiple operating systems, use FAT32, as long as you're ok with its limitations (in particular, the maximum file size is 4GB).

If you want the filesystem to be readable and writable on both Windows and Linux, use NTFS.

If you only want access from Linux: use Linux's native filesystem, i.e., ext4 if your Linux is recent enough and ext3 otherwise.

Comment: I would generally recommend against using FAT32. It easily gets fragmented, has the 4GB file size limit as you mentioned. NTFS would probably be the way to go if it's a dual boot with Windows.